# Cmake, Windows, MinGW, MSYS2

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, msys2

Смотрите.

я живу под виндой, разрабатываю на C++ и при этом я не пользуюсь ни Visual Studio, ни Microsoft'овским компилятором.

До сих пор очень хорошо себя проявлял установленный через MSYS2 пакет WinGW-64 с gcc - шными компилятором и дебаггером. А в качестве редактора - легковесная Visual Studio Code.

Однако, это порождает ряд проблем.

Мне очень тяжело собрать какой нибудь проект, взятый c github.

То, что в убунте делается тремя командами `git clone - make - make install` для меня выливается в несколько дней поисков и чтения форумов.

Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать следующее:

подавляющее большинство проектов собираются при помощи CMake.

То есть, сначала CMake, а потом уже make и make install

Но CMake, будучи запущенным под Windows, автоматически создает проект типа *.sln - солюшен для Visual Studio.

Я поискал - нашел вот такой вот [вопрос-ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098360/cmake-specifying-build-toolchain)

Но всё равно непонятно, **как при запуске CMake сказать ему, чтобы он собирал проект для обычного make. Ну, или хотя бы для чего нибудь, что я могу использовать совместно с gcc**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно мучить CMake под виндой?

Спасибо.

**Дополняю вопрос** Мне @Fat-Zer любезно подсказал, что команда должна быть такой:

`cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..`

Вот я беру hello world

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

и такого же вида heelo world в смысле cmake: CMakeLists.txt:

```
    project(HelloWorld)

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

    add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

Запускаю `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..` (во временной вложенной директории), получаю:

```
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program.
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Не могли бы Вы подсказать мне следующие шаги, что нужно сделать, чтобы проект для MSYS собирался?

Comment: думаю, `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles"` спасёт отца русской демократии... см. `man cmake-generators` и список генераторов в `cmake --help`...

Comment: *"легковесная Visual Studio Code"* - месье оптимист, *"То, что в убунте делается тремя командами git clone - make - make install"* - месье дважды оптимист...

Comment: @Fat-Zer - спасибо, я продвинулся на один шаг вперед и дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @user7860670 - я согласен, что я оптимист. Но на 90% я прав: VSC - запускается быстро, обладает некоторыми очень полезными расширениями (типа Live Share или TabNine).

Comment: @S.H., точно не скажу — я давно под win ничего не собирал и слабо представляю, что такое *msys2*... очевидно, что cmake не видит компилятор и `make`... можно попробовать запустить `cmake` «изнутри» msys2 (если эта фраза вообще имеет какой-то смысл)... может нужно прописать в `PATH` путь до компилятора/make (в составе msys2 ведь есть какой-то make?)... если первых двух вариантов недостаточно, то может тупо скормить cmake'у `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/path/to/make`, `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/gcc` и т.д.

Comment: @Fat-Zer - Спасибо. Компилятор и make конечно же есть в path, именно поэтому меня сообщение и ставит меня в такой ступор. Попробовать запустить из шелла msys2 - я попробовал, но у этой скотины собственный path  в котором нет компилятора, и все попытки прописать export PATH="C/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin:$PATH" ему как об стенку горох

Comment: a цель собрать под виндОЙ или для виндЫ?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, цель - разрабатывать под виндой, запускаться это все будет на убунте... и я убил на эти попытки уже столько времени, что всерьез думаю про альтернативный путь - VSC на винде и удаленная разработка на какой нибудь маленькой виртуалочке под убунтой

Comment: Используйте CLion, там всё это с удобным графическим интерфейсом из коробки будет работать. И не надо менять IDE и вообще что-либо кроме тулчейнов на разных ОС. Порог вхождения -- туториал по CMake, хотя уже Makefile-ы завезли

Comment: @S.H. ... убунту можно и в докере запустить, с gcc

Comment: *"Попробовать запустить из шелла msys2 - я попробовал, но у этой скотины собственный path в котором нет компилятора"* Он должен там быть, значит плохо запускаете. Используйте, например, экзешник `mingw64.exe` (или `mingw32.exe`, если хотите использовать 32-битный компилятор), тогда компилятор будет в PATH. Если все сделано правильно, то при вводе команд маджентой будет написано `MINGW64` (или 32) вместо `MSYS`. Еще убедитесь, что у вас стоит правильной компилятор, из пакета `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (или для 32 бит: `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`, а НЕ из пакета `gcc`).

Comment: *"Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set"* Пропишите их руками, кажется по умолчанию CMake ищет MSVC. Вот так: `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++`. Естественно из шелла MSYS2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, от Вас - самые ценные советы, и вообще именно по Вашим советам сейчас вся эта балалайка настроена...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запуская `cmake` с явным выбором генератора, как команда `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..`, запускать её нужно в подходящей среде, т.е. в данном случае в шелле `msys`, или её эмуляции.
Посмотреть требования `cmake` можно в соответствующем модуле, в данном случае нужно посмотреть файл `CMakeMSYSFindMake.cmake` в котором имеются инструкции для поиска программы `make` и где она ищется.

Comment: Кстати, я сам так же долго использовал ГНУшные инструменты, только `minGW`, и при условии что проект не содержит специфичных нестандартных расширений `MS` вполне нормально всё собирается без особых проблем.